# Python - Trying to count instances of a string in SSH std.out

Tags: python, string, ssh, count

I have been a lurker for some time and have learned almost everything I know from this site.  However I have ran into an issue that I have not been able to find a resolution to.  I am attempting to SSH to Cisco devices and pull information.  I am running 'sho interface status' which will give the output below:

```
 Port    Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex Speed Type
 Fa0                        connected    1          a-full   a-100 10/100BaseTX
 Fa1                        notconnect   1            auto    auto 10/100BaseTX
 Fa2                        connected    1          a-full   a-100 10/100BaseTX
 Fa3                        notconnect   313          auto    auto 10/100BaseTX
 Fa4                        notconnect   1            auto    auto 10/100BaseTX
 Fa5                        notconnect   1            auto    auto 10/100BaseTX
 Fa6                        connected    1          a-full   a-100 10/100BaseTX
 Fa7                        connected    1          a-full   a-100 10/100BaseTX"
```

I am trying to count how many lines contain the text 'notconnect'.  I have tried this many different ways and I either get and arbitrary number like 235 or I get 0.  Below is an example of what I am trying when I get weird numbers:

```
            stdin, stdout, stderr = dssh.exec_command('show interface status')
            response1 = stdout.read()
            if 'notconnect' in response1:
                            EMPTY_PORT = 0
                            for line in response1:
                                            if line.strip() and line[0]!='connected':
```

This is what I have tried when I get a response of 0:

```
            stdin, stdout, stderr = dssh.exec_command('sho int status')
            response = stdout.read()
            if 'notconnect' in response:
                data = stdout.read()
                count = data.count('not')
                EMPTY_PORT = count
                for line in response:
                        count = count + line.count("not")
```

I really hope you guys (and gals) can help steer me in the right direction.  I have been working on this same section of script for almost 6 hours. I know I am missing something here.

The only thing left that I can think of is EMPTY_PORT is what I am using to capture the count.

Comment: First order of business: Break your program up into logically grouped parts. Parsing the output of `show interface status` would be one. Copy the sample output you provided in the question into a text file, and use your parsing function on that. Does that work?

Comment: Along the same lines, separate the code that's executing the command over SSH from the rest. Then test that code separately, making sure you can issue a `show interface status` and get the raw results you expect.

Comment: The only issues I am having is with the count.  I can issue the command and get the response needed.  I am just not able to count like I would like to.

Comment: I haven't tried parsing to a file.  I was trying to stay away from local files as much as possible.  This script is going to be a mobile script and will be ran on many different computers instead of just mine.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you temporarily save the response to a file. I'm suggesting you use files with a saved response in order to test your counting code in isolation (without invoking the network code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would deal with the counting part:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

RAW_RESPONSE = """\
Port    Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex Speed Type
Fa0                        connected    1          a-full   a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa1                        notconnect   1            auto    auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa2                        connected    1          a-full   a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa3                        notconnect   313          auto    auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa4                        notconnect   1            auto    auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa5                        notconnect   1            auto    auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa6                        connected    1          a-full   a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa7                        connected    1          a-full   a-100 10/100BaseTX
"""


def count_notconnected(response):
    counter = 0
    for line in response:
        if 'notconnect' in line:
            counter += 1
    return counter


response = StringIO(RAW_RESPONSE)
print count_notconnected(response)
```

Output:

```
4
```

[`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) is just a module that allows you to wrap a string so it behaves the same way like a [file object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) - like open files or network responses: You can `read()` from it, iterate over it, etc.

This allows for testing the `count_notconnected` function with sample data, and just feed a real `response` into it once it works.

---

Your attempts don't work because in both cases you `read()` all the data from the reponse into a string at once, and then iterate over that string character by character by doing `for line in response1:` - `line` is actually a single character.

So:

- Iterating over a [file object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) will split it for you at newline boundries, and let you iterate over lines.
- Iterating over a string however, even if it contains newlines, will iterate over the string's characters.

Comment: Could not get the above to work when placed into production.  It worked as a static file.  I did find a way to get this to work though.

response = str(response)
EMPTY_PORT = response.count('notconnect')